# C++ virtual function definition

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I  need to create a virtual function in one of my classes. Admittedly I have very little experience doing this, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in the definition, but something is causing errors. My header file definition looks like this:

```
void myVirtualFunction() virtual;
```

And my class definition looks like this:

```
void myClass::myVirtualFunction()
{
  //code here...
}
```

However, when I run this, I get six errors, specifically three pairs of these two errors:

```
C2144: syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';'
```

and

```
C2208: 'int': no members defined by using this type
```

I'm really confused by this, since no where in the class (no other functions) use int as a parameter type. Does anyone know why this may happen. Thanks!

(PS: any colored formatting in the error message examples can be ignored, I wasn't sure how to undo SO's autoformatting)

Comment: This is unrelated to Qt, it's a pure C++ issue.

Comment: @MSalters: agree; edited the text and tags accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, virtual functions are declared by prepending the `virtual` keyword to the function's declaration in the class. Thus your declaration should be:

```
virtual void myVirtualFunction();
```